How to get difference blend mode effect with flutter_svg
I have tired this but it doesn't work like expected also tired other modes but doesn't match the effect i need.
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
    ),
    SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/logo.svg',
      ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white, BlendMode.difference),
    )
  ],
)





tried to set colorFilter: ... and not colorBlendMode: ...?

In case none of the answers work, simply download it as an SVG and use it.

@pskink well i have tired color filter, coorBlendMode with color none of them work

@Aks bro i need dynamic because the color and logo will change.

its like having white box and black github logo

Add this package: widget_mask. This package contains a class "SaveLayer" we can use like this ->
##You can handle the position of svg as needed.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:widget_mask/widget_mask.dart';


class BlendTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlendTest({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: SaveLayer(
                    paint: Paint()..blendMode = BlendMode.difference,
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          "assets/github.svg",
                         // colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white, BlendMode.srcIn),
                        )
                        )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}



Thanks that exactly what i need one thing if i have not white logo by default this doesn't work so need to set color param for svg to white

What that means? Like you have a svg with red color then you want to change it to white color? Can you add an image what you want to achieve? And if suggested edit is applied then it'll not look like your reference image as you are not using any Position.

Updated the answer and You can try to uncomment the "colorFilter" and check with your other svgs.

see my answer as i cant attach image in comment so created answer to reply your questions.

Can't attach reference image in comment thats why answering @Aks question here with image reference.
When logo is not white like black or red then need to set color parameter as White of SvgPicture.asset as shown in below image original logo was black.
Then about my updated code the effect is same as @Aks use SizedBox with Postponed Widgets but i use Stack alignment property with Padding on SVG.


Have you tried? colorFilter inside SvgPicture.asset().?

no i havent yet.
